# configure visual studio with nuget package, VSIX automatically

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package, vsix, nuget-server

I have to configure nugets amd VSIX in my visual studio. We are right now doing it manually by adding the package source under Tools -> Options -> Enviroments / Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package manager.

I need to populate the feed/URL for nuget and VSIX automatically when we open Tools -> Options in Visual studio so that the user should just select the respective feed and install it, to remove the manual overhead of adding the url for installing nugets/VSIX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget gallery can be programmatically configured for the required nuget feed. We have done it by writing a custom control. In our system, under 'AppData' folder, there is a file called **Nuget.config**.

In this file all the Nuget fields are listed and as a result the user can see those Nuget feeds in Visual Studio ->  Tools -> Options -> Enviroments / Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package manager.

To add your Nuget Feed, you just need to modify the **Nuget.Config** file and add your feed to it. Below is the Code:

```
[CustomAction]        
    public static ActionResult ConfigAdeptNuGetFeed(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("*** Begin ConfigAdeptNuGetFeed ***");

        var result = ActionResult.Failure;
        if (File.Exists(XDocPath))
        {
            session.Log("Nuget.config was found in the %appdata% folder.");
            try
            {
                var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.Load(XDocPath);
                var baseNode = xDoc.DocumentElement;

                if (baseNode != null)
                {
                    session.Log($"{baseNode.Name} has {baseNode.ChildNodes.Count} child elements.");
                    session.Log($"XML before install: {baseNode.OuterXml}");
                    if (baseNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 2)
                    {

                        //Checks for the AdeptNugetfeed.    
                        var node =
                            baseNode.SelectSingleNode($"//add[@value='{AdeptInstaller.AdeptNuGetFeedPath}']");

                        //AdeptFeed not found, adding it.
                        if (node == null)
                        {
                            session.Log("Adept Feed not present. Adding it now.");
                            var packageNode = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("packageSources")[0];
                            var newElement = xDoc.CreateElement("add");
                            var xAttribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("key");
                            xAttribute.Value = "AdeptNugetFeed";
                            var xAttributeVal = xDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
                            xAttributeVal.Value = AdeptInstaller.AdeptNuGetFeedPath;
                            newElement.Attributes.Append(xAttribute);
                            newElement.Attributes.Append(xAttributeVal);
                            packageNode.AppendChild(newElement);

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            session.Log("Adept feed is already present. Nothing to do.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        session.Log($"{baseNode.Name} is empty.");
                        baseNode.InnerXml = AdeptInstaller.NuGetFullConfig;

                    }
                    xDoc.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Nuget", "Nuget.config"));
                    session.Log($"XML after install: {baseNode.OuterXml}");
                }
                else
                {
                    session.Log("NuGet.config file is invalid... abbending.");
                    throw new XmlException("XML issue with the reading of the nuget.config file.");
                }
                result = ActionResult.Success;
            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                session.Log(exc.ToString());
                result = ActionResult.Failure;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(AdeptInstaller.Nuget_config_file_not_found);
            result = ActionResult.Failure;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to run powershell comand [Register-PackageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-6) e.g.

```
Register-PackageSource -Name "My package source" -Location "C:\MyNugetPackages" -ProviderName "NuGet"
```

which will add the package source also to the Visual studio setings.

To run the powershell comand from C# look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joeb/2017/12/04/running-powershell-from-c/) or C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678273/how-to-call-a-powershell-script-from-a-c-code).