# How to call a powershell script from a C code

Tags: c++, c, powershell, directory, directory-listing

In my case, I needed to call a powershell script from a c or c++ code source, found few links which were pretty clumsy and not good with c++,  I simply want a roadmap if its possible invoking a powershell script which lists directory contents from a code snippet written in c or c++

Comment: C++ code will be fine for you as you tagged the question C and C++ ?

Comment: Hie. C would be more lucid to me!

Answer (score 11):

C++ code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <io.h>   // For access().
#include <sys/types.h>  // For stat().
#include <sys/stat.h>   // For stat().
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
       string strPath = "d:\\callPowerShell.ps1";
//access function:
       //The function returns 0 if the file has the given mode.
       //The function returns –1 if the named file does not exist or does not have the given mode
       if(access(strPath.c_str(),0) == 0)
       {

              system("start powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned \n");
              system("start powershell.exe d:\\callPowerShell.ps1");
              system("cls");
       }
       else
       {
              system("cls");
              cout << "File is not exist";
              system("pause");
       }
}
```

Comment: It'll be better if you'd supply `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter right in the same command with the script. Also `strPath` is assigned but not used.

Comment: For future reference, this answer can be greatly improved with vc++17 supporting c++17 and therefore the filesystem TS allowing `std::filesystem::exists(...);` rather than system specific includes and functions. Also use of `std::system` rather than just C's `system` is recommended, `using namespace std;` could cause redefinition issues for the `system` function.

Comment: after running Set-ExecutionPolicy command the dialog asks to confirm ` Do you want to change the execution policy?`. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 3):

First error :

```
#include <io.h>   // For access().
```

access is in this lib:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Next :

> error: 'system' was not declared in this scope

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

And finally :

The caractere `'\'` is a special caractere for C/C++ then you have to add another `'\'` like :

```
system("start powershell.exe C:\\users\\sqtk-mal\\script1.ps1");
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++

```
#include <cstdlib>

std::system("command");
```

In c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system("command");
```